# Hbase table populated with value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 from scala code

Tags: hbase

When I try to put the Row key with one column as Double  into an Hbase table by scala program  , I am seeing this kind of 32 bit representation in output file (Hbase table).This is a completely stopping my work.

Please advise how we can get the correct representation for 'Double' type field  in Hbase Table.

Code related for this is below:Am I missing something here?

```
VarValue_Output: Double
p(3).toDouble
final val colVarValueBytes = Bytes.toBytes("VarValue_Output")
put.add(cfDataBytes, colVarValueBytes, Bytes.toBytes(Data.VarValue_Output)
```

Thanks
Vijaya Kumar Pabothu

Answer (score 0):

It's expected behaviour.
You've saved `Double` data type, but HBase shell (I assume you're using it) does not know about it anything (everything in HBase is represented as byte array). So by default it's trying to extract String from your byte array and obviously shows some uninformative list of unicode symbols:

`Bytes.toBytes("15.0")` does not equal to `Bytes.toBytes(15.0)`

1. Try to save it as string, transformed to byte array (and you'll be able to read in base shell)
2. Read it from your application, and make sure you're transforming your column value `Bytes.toDouble`

Comment: Please see my code below, Please advise where I am doing wrong.

Comment: def convertToPut(sensor: Sensor): (ImmutableBytesWritable, Put) = {
      val dateTime = sensor.TimeStamp_Output
      val rowkey = sensor.ToolName_Output + "_" + dateTime
      val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowkey))
      put.add(cfDataBytes, colLookupBytes, Bytes.toBytes(sensor.Lookup))
   put.add(cfDataBytes, colVarNameBytes, Bytes.toBytes(sensor.VarName_Output))
      put.add(cfDataBytes, colVarValueBytes, Bytes.toBytes(sensor.VarValue_Output)) 
      return (new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(rowkey)), put)
    }

Comment: Definition--final val colVarValueBytes = Bytes.toBytes("VarValue_Output")

Comment: case class Sensor(Lookup: String, ToolName_Output: String,VarName_Output: String, VarValue_Output:Double , TimeStamp_Output: String)

Comment: object Sensor extends Serializable {
  
     def parseSensor(str: String): Sensor = {
      val p = str.split(",")
      Sensor(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3).toDouble, p(4))
    }

Comment: Issue is with only  the column  VarValue_Output - Populating with wrong values in Hbase file \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00